# Gitlab what should base domain for ingress be if more than 1 cluster?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have two clusters.

One where the environment is set to staging and one where it is production.

When I just had one cluster for the base domain I entered the domain I was using for a subdomain to access my gitlab via: `gitlab.mydomain.com`

So in my domain provider I set `*.mydomain.com` to the IP that the ingress provided me.

Now that I have an extra cluster (for staging) I am unsure what to enter for the base domain and in the domain provider what to enter (`*.staging.mydomain.com`) ?

I am also assuming for my projects that have their own domains, that I can just point their domain provider to the ingress IP for each ingress like:

> *.projectdomain.com = cluster1-ingress-production-ip

and

> *.staging.projectdomain.com = cluster2-ingress-staging-ip

In the gitlab-ci for staging it would be like:

```yaml
    deploy_review:
      image:
        name: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest
        entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      stage: review
      only:
        - branches
      except:
        - tags
      environment:
        name: staging
        url: https://$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.projectdomain.com
        on_stop: stop_review
```

In the gitlab-ci for production it would be something like:

```yaml
    deploy:
      image:
        name: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest
        entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      stage: deploy
      environment:
        name: production
        url: https://projectdomain.com/
```

Comment: Are you talking about `Kubernetes` clusters managed through [GitLab Cluster Environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/environments.html) ?

Comment: In my admin area, on the Kuberenetes tab I have two clusters, each with a different Environment scope: production and staging. Each of the clusters has a different IP adderess shown on the ingress application field on both of the clusters applications tab. When I connected each cluster a runner was auto added to the runners page under the shared scope.